# Spring MVC requests processing order

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a web service that receives some data from clients and saves them to a Map

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {
    private final Map<String, String> state = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/set-state", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public synchronized @ResponseBody void setState(@RequestParam String id,
            @RequestBody String updatedData) {
        state.put(id, updatedData);
    }
}
```

Suppose that a client sends two requests one after another. Both requests have the same id, but the second request has updated data.

The question is, does Spring MVC guarantee that `setState` will be called with request 1 data first? Is making the method synchronized enough to make sure I'll always get the updated data from request 2 in the state Map?

Comment: Does the client wait to send the second request until the first has received a response? Or are they sent in parallel?

Comment: The client just writes the data to `OutputStream` and closes it. It can send another request immediately after it, but not in parallel. The client doesn't expect some response from the service, hence I use `@ResponseBody void`.

Comment: If the requests are sent sequentially (full request/response cycle) by the client, then your order is guaranteed regardless of the server's behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw my comment above. So does it mean that as it is now, the order is not guaranteed and I should add at least `getResponseCode()` to the client code for it to wait for the response before sending another request?

Comment: Sure, that will effectively achieve the sequential-ity I was talking about. Note that this is (almost) independent of the behavior of the server.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.